# Why is this telling me thehash2 is not a template?

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm very confused as to why Terminal is telling me that thehash2 is not a template when I try to compile.

Am I crazy?

```
template<typename Symbol>
class thehash
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const Symbol & item)
    {
        static thehash2<string> hf;
        return hf(item.getData());
    }
};


template<typename string>
class thehash2<string>
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const string & key)
    {
        size_t hashVal = 0;
        for(char ch : key)
            hashVal = 37 * hashVal + ch;
        return hashVal;
    }
};
```

Comment: Simple syntax error; don't put `<string>` after `class thehash2`. Also I recommend using something other than `string` for the template parameter name as it's *very* confusing; the reader will likely initially think you're referring to `std::string`.

Comment: You need to define or at least declare `hash2` *before* using it.

Comment: `template<typename string>
class thehash2<string>` is simply wrong syntax to derive!!

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename string>
class thehash2<string>
{
```

Here's an error. You might wanted to write:

```
template<typename T>
class thehash2
{
```

Note, that - as stated in comments - you shouldn't use `string` as a typename in template. Most common names for template parameters are usually single letters - `T`, `U`, ... such that they won't be easily confused with real type names.

Second option:

```
class thehash2 : public thehash<std::string>
{
```

(depending on your actual needs)